# How do I automate a command line script with Java ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, command-line, automation, processbuilder

I'm relative newbie to java and am trying to automate command line using java. I tried to search for the solution here, but couldn't find it.

I created a simple test shell script like below for testing my program:

---

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "What is your name?";
read name;
echo "Hello, $name"
echo "What is your contact number?";
read num;
echo "Saved contact number $num for $name"
```

---

The Java code is below:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class CmdLineMain {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
        command.add("./test.sh");

        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);

        final Process process = builder.start();
        InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line = "";
        BufferedWriter bw = null;

        while (process.isAlive()) {
            line = br.readLine();
            // since stream may be closed earlier, re-open it
            bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream()));
            System.out.println(line);

            if (line != null) {
                switch (line) {
                case "What is your name?":
                    bw.write("John Doe");
                    bw.close();
                    break;
                case "What is your contact number?":
                    bw.write("123456789");
                    bw.close();
                    break;

                }
            }

        }

        System.out.println("Program terminated!");
    }
}
```

---

Problem: The second input to the process fails with error:

---

```
    What is your name?
    Hello, John Doe
    What is your contact number?
    Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
        at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(FilterOutputStream.java:158)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implClose(StreamEncoder.java:320)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.close(StreamEncoder.java:149)
        at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.close(OutputStreamWriter.java:233)
        at java.io.BufferedWriter.close(BufferedWriter.java:266)
        at nkh.app.CmdLineMain.main(CmdLineMain.java:34)
```

---

Comment: Did you try to set the buffered writer and close it **outside** the loop? By the way it's not a good idea to reinstance a new one every loop turn.

Comment: I noted that unless I close() the writer, the script wouldn't proceed further. close seems to be the only way the script would proceed to "Hello, John Doe" and the next output

Comment: Could you elaborate or post a working sample? before trying close() I tried flush() but it didn't continue with the script either. Thanks,

Comment: @user2054627 did my code not work? I have a sample.

Comment: Yes it did, and I've accepted your answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closing the `BufferedWriter` will close its underlying streams, this includes the process `OutputStream` which you get through `process.getOutputStream()`. Thus, once it is closed in one loop, in the next loops you have your `BufferedWriter` wrapping a closed stream. Instead wrap the output stream only once and reuse that.

Like this:

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream()));
// while the stream is open and there is something to read
// probably a better condition than `process.isAlive()`
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    switch (line) {
        case "What is your name?":
            bw.write("John Doe");
            bw.newLine();
            bw.flush();
            break;
        case "What is your contact number?":
            bw.write("123456789");
            bw.newLine();
            bw.flush();
            break;
    }
}
```

---

The reason your original code died on `close()` rather than on the `write()` that came before it when your new `BufferedWriter` was wrapping the closed underlying stream was because `BufferedOutputStream.write()` may not actually write to the underlying stream yet, since it's buffered. Calling `flush()` should tell the stream to actually write, and as you see in the stack trace `close()` is calling `flush()` which is ultimately writing the buffered bytes to the underlying `FileOutputStream`, which is then realizing that the `FileOutputStream` is already closed.

Comment: Thanks, I think I tried this earlier, but will re-test and let you know

Comment: So the bw.newLine() it what's making the script go ahead. Seems obvious now after seeing your answer. :)

Comment: @user2054627 No problem. I recommend also using a try-with-resources, to ensure your streams get closed at the end and probably use  `(line = br.readLine()) != null` as your loop invariant.

Comment: @Amessihel I believe so, just like when you're typing into a console you press enter to create a newline and complete a command. The process needs to know where a command ends.

Comment: Mmh, question: if the `BufferedWriter` wraps a closed stream on the second part, why it's not the `write()` call which throws the Exception, but the `close()` one?

Comment: Because the `BufferedOutputStream` may not have `actually` written to the underlying stream yet, since it's buffered. Calling `close` or `flush` should force the stream to write, and as you see in the stack trace `close()` is calling `flush()` which is writing the buffered bytes to the underlying `FileOutputStream`, which is then realizing that the `FileOutputStream` is already closed.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. Thanks.